# How to use date.js through Puppeteer exposeFunction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am using `puppeteer 1.19.0` and `date.js 0.3.3` for this example

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const date = require('date.js');

let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.exposeFunction('formatDate', (text) =>
    date(text));

    await page.goto('https://www.daraz.com.bd/products/the-vip-suction-mobile-phone-stand-pocket-size-i113492895-s1030756115.html');
    await page.waitFor(1000);

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll('#module_product_qna > div.pdp-mod-qna > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li')
        for (var element of elements)
        {
            let question = element.querySelector('div:first-of-type > div.qna-content').innerText;
            let qtime = element.querySelector('div:first-of-type > div.qna-meta').innerText;
            let q = qtime.match(/- (.+)/);
            qtime = formatDate(q[1]);         
            return {
                question,
                qtime             
            }
    }});

    browser.close();
    return result;
};

scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

You can see I am trying to use date function of [**date.js**](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/date) library to parse relative date through puppeteer [**exposeFunction**](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) but date function is not working inside page context. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn´t work?"

Comment: I mean the date function is working fine outside page context. but it is not working inside page evaluate function.

Comment: You need to import the library in the own page that you are scraping

Comment: @Rashomon will you please elaborate? what do you mean by own page?

Comment: Sorry, didnt realize you have already used `exposeFunction`. Can you try to access `formatDate` using `window.formatDate` ?

Comment: @Rashomon Tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From puppeteer [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction):

> The method adds a function called `name` on the page's `window` object.
>   When called, the function executes `puppeteerFunction` in node.js and
>   returns a Promise which resolves to the return value of
>   `puppeteerFunction`.

Try this:

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(async() => {
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll('#module_product_qna > div.pdp-mod-qna > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li')
        for (var element of elements)
        {
            let question = element.querySelector('div:first-of-type > div.qna-content').innerText;
            let qtime = element.querySelector('div:first-of-type > div.qna-meta').innerText;
            let q = qtime.match(/- (.+)/);
            qtime = await window.formatDate(q[1]);         
            return {
                question,
                qtime             
            }
    }});
```